# Why does my laptop screen dim after a few seconds on battery power?

Tags: debian, dconf

It isn't actually locking or going to sleep. After a few seconds, the screen just clicks to a slightly darker setting. I have looked through dconf editor and the settings menu, and can't find any. Someone on here asked a similar question about Fedora, but it was a system update that fixed it. I'm running Debian 9, so that won't work for me. Below I will include a screenshot of my dconf power menu:
[image: dconf photo]
To be clear, this issue doesn't plague me when the laptop is plugged in. But when it's unplugged, the computer gets noticeably darker after just a few seconds of idling.

Also, the screen brightens back up as soon as I touch the mouse or the keyboard.

**Solved, kind of**: While dealing with some other issues, I rebooted my computer a few times (something I hadn't done since messing with dconf) and the issues seems to have gone away. So perhaps it was just necessary to reboot after editing?

Comment: could be a bug in gnome?

Comment: Maybe, that would be extremely irritating. I don’t know what to do if that’s the case.

Comment: open a bug in the gnome bugtracker: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/

Answer (score 0):

Especially on Laptops, the [embedded controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller) (EC) does a lot of things, including power management and controlling of the backlight.

Unfortunately, every vendor does this differently, and none of this is documented somewhere. For Windows, the pre-installed drivers reasonably support it; for Linux, the situation is difficult because of the diversity and lack of documentation.

So I very much suspect it is the EC that turns down your backlight after a few seconds of confirming that there's no power from the power supply. (My laptop does this instantly). If that is the case, looking at Gnome settings or filing a bug is not going to help.

On my laptop, I can turn the brightness up again manually. See if this works on your laptop. If you are lucky, the EC produces an ACPI event (or some sort of event) you can catch with a custom script, and then turn the backlight back up automatically, but how this works (if at all) will depend entirely on your laptop, so you need to do a bit of reading and sleuthing. E.g. try `acpi_listen`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into that. I just edited the question to reflect this, but I don't have to manually turn up the brightness again in the sense of changing the setting; as soon as I touch the mousepad or the keyboard the screen brightens back up.

Comment: Then I'd suspect some kind of "display power saving mode if you are not using it" executed on the EC. And I bet you can turn it off somehow. Do you still have the Windows drivers for it? Any settings for that in those?

Comment: My laptop is dual booting Windows 10 and Debian 9, so I would think I do still have windows drivers. Should I poke around in the settings of the Windows partition?

Comment: Yes, definitely look at the Windows drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As of a few days ago (~10-Sept-2018) my laptop, a ThinkPad X1c5, running GNOME on stock Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-34) has developed a similar issue when running on battery: if I leave it idle for just 15 secs without keyboard or mouse input, it dims automatically.  This is 100% reproducible.  I have applied all updates and rebooted a couple of times to no avail.

Thankfully, OP's screenshot has suggested a workaround: simply set `idle-brightness` to 100% (or whatever your regular brightness setting is).

A way to achieve this with the CLI is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 100
```

You can also use the dconf-editor to achieve this as shown on the OP's screenshot.  The obvious solution of switching off `idle-dim` doesn't work.  This means that you loose the regular (useful) auto-dimming which would normally occur within 15 minutes or so of inactivity.

Needless to say this isn't very conducive to focus when trying to do productivity work (where the odd thinking pause is required, eg: for coding) so I rather hope this is a bug rather than some sort of executive decision of what's "best" for the user.